# innodb buffer pool size not changing

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, percona-server

I have Percona fork of MySQL 5.7 installed where I have defined **innodb_buffer_pool_size** in **/etc/percona-server.conf.d/mysqld.cnf** as follows

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 10G
```

But, when I login to MySQL prompt and run command show global variables like 'innodb_buffer_pool_size' it shows as follows

```
mysql> show global variables like 'innodb_buffer_pool_size';
+-------------------------+-----------+
| Variable_name           | Value     |
+-------------------------+-----------+
| innodb_buffer_pool_size | 134217728 |
+-------------------------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

and no matter what value I set in **/etc/percona-server.conf.d/mysqld.cnf** for **innodb_buffer_pool_size** the value for **innodb_buffer_pool_size** in MySQL prompt remains same.

Also, when I run **show global variables like 'innodb_buffer_pool_%size'** in MySQL prompt it shows as follows

```
mysql> show global variables like 'innodb_buffer_pool_%size' ;
+-------------------------------+-----------+
| Variable_name                 | Value     |
+-------------------------------+-----------+
| innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size | 134217728 |
| innodb_buffer_pool_size       | 134217728 |
+-------------------------------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Can someone tell me why innodb_buffer_pool_size value is not changing? while I have enough memory on my server.

Comment: When you restarted the server did you get any parse errors in the conf file?

Comment: Are you certain you're editing the correct file? Run: `mysqld --verbose --help | grep -A 1 "Default options"`

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ Yes, when I run command `mysqld --verbose --help | grep -A 1 "Default options"` I did not find the path for /etc/percona-server.conf.d so I had to add `!includedir /etc/percona-server.conf.d` in the end of /etc/my.cnf and then it worked. But, I am just curious about, if lets say `symbolic-links=0` or `datadir` is defined in both files then which one will take precedence and why?

Answer (score 1):

Repeating the above comment to provide an "answer" for this question:
The config file `/etc/percona-server.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` was not being included in the standard "global config" file, commonly known at `/etc/my.cnf`. @OP added `!includedir /etc/percona-server.conf.d` to the end of the global config and then the changes were visible upon restart of MySQL.